# Qual o erro no laço while? liguagem lua

Tags: lua, while

Qual o erro no laço? Escrevi esse código para imprimir a soma dos 10 primeiros números primos, já revisei os laços mas não consegui achar o erro. Era pra imprimir a soma dos primos até 29 mas só imprimi 2. Vlwzao o/

```
n=2
cont=0
soma=0


while n<=29 do
k=1
    while k<=n do
        if n%k==0 then
            cont=cont+1
        end
    k=k+1
    end
    if cont==2 then
        soma=soma+n
    else soma=soma
    end
n=n+1
end 
print(soma)
```

Comment: Qual o sintoma que te diz que tem algum erro?

Comment: na hora do print da soma o valor que imprimi é 2, era pra imprimir a soma dos numeros primos ate 29.

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca essa informação, por favor

Comment: 2+3+5+7+11+13+17+19+23+29=129

Comment: Faltou você zerar a variável `cont` dentro do `while`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltou você zerar a variável `cont` dentro do `while`:

```
while n<=29 do
k=1
cont = 0
...
```